# Hardhat smart contract deployment without Alchemy

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

How do I avoid centralized networks when deploying hardhat?

After taking multiple tutorials, I find that either Infura or Alchemy (centralized vendors) are used throughout.

E.g.

```
$cat hardhat.config.js 

require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: "https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/ALCHEMY_KEY",
      accounts: ["0xPRIV_KEY"]
    }
  },
  solidity: "0.8.9"
};
```

Does any public, or decentralized, alternatives exist to Alchemy?

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum is a P2P network where each member of the network is described as a node. Each node can broadcast a signed transaction to the rest of the network, and the transaction is later picked up by a miner/validator to be included in a block.

Alchemy and Infura are widely used 3rd party node providers. Node provider is a service that accepts a signed transaction over an API and then, using Ethereum node on their server, broadcasts the transaction to the rest of the network.

So the "simplest" and most decentralized alternative to a 3rd party node provider is to [run your own node](https://ethereum.org/en/run-a-node/), for example with [go-ethereum](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started).

I'm not aware of any 3rd party Ethereum provider that would be free to use publicly without registration... There are some [public nodes](https://docs.bscscan.com/misc-tools-and-utilities/public-rpc-nodes) for Binance Smart Chain (that also uses EVM - Ethereum Virtual Machine) maintained by Binance and other of their partnered companies.